# Weird issue during migration from Swift 2 to Swift 3: Initializer has different argument names from those required by protocol

Tags: swift, swift3, swift2

I'm trying to migrate this (https://github.com/emilwojtaszek/leveldb-swift) project from Swift 2 to Swift 3. I've cleared all 100+ errors during migration except this following one:

```
Initializer 'init(bytes:count:)' has different argument names from those required by protocol 'KeyType' ('init(bytes:length:)')
```

I was struggling to figure out the reason for it past couple of hours and getting no clue of what the problem is, any thoughts?

P.S.

Here is the link to project with current state of migration:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pR6-NrJFYGOwYyLLg_SbYNCQ9lyF6Ljc/view?usp=sharing

Here is an screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 2 we used to have NSData with the initializer [init(bytes:length:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1412793-init). Since Apple has done a lot of renaming in Swift 3, NSData is called Data and the initializer is called [init(bytes:count:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1780158-init) now.

So everything you need to do is to update your KeyType protocol:

```
public protocol KeyType {
    init(bytes: UnsafeRawPointer, count: Int) // change "length" to "count"
    func withSlice(_ f: (Slice) -> ())
    func asData() -> Data
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! Would be thankful if you select the answer.

Comment: Sure thing! Don't know why I haven't done it initially, btw, here's a continuation of this journey https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47677187/import-third-party-c-library-into-swift-causes-error-include-of-non-modular-hea