# Import third party C library into swift causes error "Include of non-modular header inside framework module"

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

This question is a continuation of a [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662932/weird-issue-during-migration-from-swift-2-to-swift-3-initializer-has-different) I'm currently migrating this (https://github.com/emilwojtaszek/leveldb-swift) library from swift 2 to swift 3/4. Here is the link to my fork https://github.com/lu4/leveldb-swift/tree/MigrationFromSwift2ToSwift3 (please note that the target branch is MigrationFromSwift2ToSwift3)

I was able to resolve (with many thanks to @Ruslan Serebriakov) all of the issues with initial code base and check that the code is running.

However after trying to update LevelDB C code to latest master I got new type of error which I don't understand how to resolve:

Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'LevelDB.c': '/Path/to/Project/leveldb-swift-migration/vendor/leveldb/include/leveldb/export.h'

I've did some research on the internet but the issues described there seem non-related with one I've stumbled on. Here is an image of the issue

[image: Issue]

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: This issue is because the SDK u are importing is not modular or u can say modulemap file is missing. So make sure modulemap file should be available inside the framework folder. Also make sure that all public headers are listed explicitly in the modulemap. This issue will be resolve 100% if module map file will be include in the third party framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm never 100% certain with mixed language frameworks. But an error *like* this happens in Swift projects when:

- since you cannot use a Bridging Header in frameworks,
- you `#import` a C header in the `Foo-Framework.h` to expose it so the Swift code, and
- the header is not itself marked "Public" to the target.

"Non-modular" seems to indicate "not part of the published module interface". At least with Swift--C mixes, you can only combine both through making the C headers public; no way to import private header files there, which is weird.

Give it a shot: Since you are obviously importing the file in non-Swift code, try to locate the `export.h` header file in your Xcode project, open the File inspector (⌘⌥1), and ensure public visibility in the framework target:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because the SDK u are importing is not modular or u can say modulemap file is missing. So make sure modulemap file should be available inside the framework folder. Also make sure that all public headers are listed explicitly in the modulemap. This issue will be resolve 100% if module map file will be include in the third party framework.